# Tar folder with backslash in the name

Tags: linux, tar

I am trying to archive a directory which has several backslashes in the name. My directory name is "\\abc\pqr\xyz". Here is the command I used.

```
tar -czf abc.tar "\\\\abc\\pqr\\xyz"
```

I was getting this error.

```
tar: \\abc\pqr\\xyz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: Try single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes. You can test with echo:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "\\\\abc\\pqr\\xyz"
echo '\\\\abc\\pqr\\xyz'
```